# When you add a new node to a cluster, what do you do to the default services?

Tags: centos, service, chkconfig

Everytime I acquire a new server or reload an existing server (CentOS 6.X) I have to decide what services to leave running in chkconfig. It seems the datacenter staff aren't using a single edition of CentOS and sometimes the default services running are different. I'm always inclined to turn off every service I've never heard of but then I think, if it's not broken don't fix it.

How do you deal with the default services in a new installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a standard build using something like `cobbler`.

In the build, configure your `kickstart` to enable only the services you absolutely need on every server. This creates a lowest common denominator.

Then, use `puppet` to differentiate each server depending on their particular purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I would automate my configurations. If you think something has changed, or a new machine is set up properly, you can cover all the bases and use Puppet to manage the server.

If you don't want to do that across a network, you can run the Puppet server and client instances on the same server and manage them with individual local Puppet configs.

Answer (score 0):

- enable definitely needed
- disable obviously not needed
- leave other as is